# Gradle sync error

Tags: android-studio, gradle

After installing Android studio for first time, the gradle didn't sync.

The dependency is this: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`
so after watching some tutorials I downloaded and extracted `gradle-3.3-all.zip` in the .gradle folder.
Still it won't work and this is the error:

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible
>   with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's
>   system information and then contact the software publisher.

I'm using windows 32 bit btw.

This is my first time with android studio so pretty much everything in it is Greek for me. Please help.

Comment: You need an internet connection to sync. Check your internet connection and firewall.

Comment: internet connection is fine and firewall is not blocking anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not compatible with the version of Windows you're running

The download button on the Android Studio page is the installer for the 64 bit version, as far as I know, which is recommended since almost all newer computers are running 64 bit.

If you really want to continue using 32bit operating system, you're going to need to [scroll down the page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) to actually download and setup that one.

Comment: I feel so stupid, I spent hours trying to figure out the problem...but they could at least mention it in that big green button which only says WINDOWS